# Xamarin barcode app Zxing.Net.Mobile not working

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I followed this tutorial "https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile" when I use Live Preview and pair it with my android device and try to hit scan button the code breaks and it gives error like "Exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' was thrown".

The error is thrown on very first line.

```
var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();
```

I 'm new to this one and not sure how to solve, if possible please let me know any barcode code which reads as well as scan in Visual studio 2017.

Comment: Do not use Live Player, it is not going to support Zxing... LivePlayer core focus is to preview the layout of XAML pages and is not a full debugging solution. Run your project directly against the emulator/device.

Comment: @SushiHangover how to run the project against the emulator ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks however I guess it requires HAXM to be installed and Hyper-V to be disabled, I need Hyper-V for docker so I can't disable that, could you please give some workaround to start the application, I tried UWP but it shows white background and red line horizontally on center so need something to work.

Comment: You could use the "older" Microsoft/VS-based android emulator as it uses Hyper-V...   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/visual-studio-emulator-for-android Or connect an actual Android device to your PC... Also you can use Docker on Windows without Hyper-V

Comment: @SushiHangover ok connecting actual android device then could you please give me steps to run ?

Comment: I already gave you a link above.... Or just use Google/Bing to find the answer.

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

So I have checked in the github as well, its clear from forum that live preview has issues related to System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException so either have device connected or install some emulator and check.